# select id not exist in other table, additional condition

Tags: sql, join

im intend to return i.e an id where it doesn't exist in other table.(e.g. transactions), with additional condition

users table

[image: users table]

transactions table

[image: transactions table]

aim was return id and name from users table which do not exist in transactions table, with join in users.id to transactions.investor_id (23xx) and join in users.id to transactions.borrower_id (100xx), which i a set the result should be (2331,2332,10011,10012), While i also want to give an additional condition which the id want to return both in investor and borrower was using gmail email address and phone number i.e 0811xx,0812xx,0813xx.

the following still returns wrong result and also contains id where iam not intended to related to the additional where condition, while still not join to the borrower_id.

```
SELECT 
    users.id, users.name 
FROM  
    users  
WHERE 
    users.id NOT IN (SELECT transactions.investor_id FROM transactions) 
    AND email LIKE '%@gmail%'
    AND phone LIKE '0811%' OR phone LIKE '0812%' OR phone LIKE '0813%'
```

Comment: For a starters, if you have `AND` and `OR` filtering I would group them like so `WHERE ... AND ... AND (... OR ... OR ... )`. But what result do you get and what would you expect?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the lack of parentheses around the `or` clauses.

But, you can simplify your query.  Most databases support some form of regular expressions.  If so, you can simplify the query to:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name 
FROM users u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT t.investor_id FROM transactions t)  AND
      u.email LIKE '%@gmail%' AND
      u.phone ~ '^081[123]';
```

The above happens to be Postgres syntax, but there is similar functionality in most databases.

I should point out that SQL Server does this with `like`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name 
FROM users u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT t.investor_id FROM transactions t)  AND
      u.email LIKE '%@gmail%' AND
      u.phone LIKE '081[123]%';
```

Or you can even do:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name 
FROM users u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT t.investor_id FROM transactions t)  AND
      u.email LIKE '%@gmail%' AND
      LEFT(u.phone, 4) IN ('0811', '0812', '0813');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Put the `OR` conditions in brackets...

```
SELECT users.id,
    users.name
FROM users 
WHERE users.id NOT IN (
        SELECT transactions.investor_id
        FROM transactions
    )
    AND email LIKE '%@gmail%'
    AND (
        phone LIKE '0811%'
        OR phone LIKE '0812%'
        OR phone LIKE '0813%'
    )
```